# How to plot a data set with treatment, weeks as a geom_line with multiple lines for treatment?

Tags: r, ggplot2, diagram

[data set](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4WtMt.png)
[code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6vz0Z.png)

I want to plot this data as a line or point plot. x should be time and y should be pH. Then the plot should create a geom_smooth for each of the four treatments, so that there will be a plot showing 4 lines (for each treatment).

[code tried](https://i.stack.imgur.com/shfup.png)
[recieved plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ece8q.png)
[what i hoped for, picture from a random data set](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7cxbw.png)
[line plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rP2u1.png)

I tried using geom_point with geom_smooth, but it looks like in the recieved plot picture. I hoped for a plot similar to the 'what i hoped for' picture.
I also tried a line plot, but it looked like in the fourth picture.

Comment: Your x axis is categorical, not numeric. To get the lines to join, add `group = trt` inside `aes`. Please don't post _images_ of data or code. Supply them as text. We cannot copy and paste images of data or code into our consoles to reproduce your problem. Please make questions reproducible.

Comment: Hey, thank you for your answer. Next time I will add the code, so one can copy it thank you. The solution worked. It looks a bit weird, but maybe a boxplot would be a better display of the data.

Comment: From the look of your data I wonder whether package {morse} might be useful for your research: https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/morse/vignettes/tutorial.html